IB Insync Futures Order on Interactive Brokers TWS API not going through
I am having trouble sending a futures order to IB TWS API. The stock order goes through fine, but nothing happens when I send a futures order.
What am I doing wrong here:
order = MarketOrder("BUY",1,account=app.ib.wrapper.accounts[0])
contract1 = Contract();
contract1.Symbol = "ES";
contract1.SecType = "FUT";
contract1.Exchange = "GLOBEX";
contract1.Currency = "USD";
contract1.LastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "202409";
app.ib.placeOrder(contract1, order)  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #IB Connection
    #Connect to IB on init
    app.ib = IB()
    
    app.ib.errorEvent += onError
    app.run(port=5000)

If I replace the contract with:
contract = Stock('SPY', 'SMART', 'USD')

It sends the order fine. Any ideas?

They changed the exchange names a couple years ago, use CME
